# Create new log file after reaching specified size?

Tags: logging

I am using JBoss 6.2 EAP. My server.log file is huge in production. How can I create a new log file after reaching specified size?

The `server.log` file is located in `standalone/log/server.log`.

I have added a rolling appender in `log4j.xml` but that did not work.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: <appender name="file" value="//192.168.42.219/Newgen/EAP_Oracle/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/server.log" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
             <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH\:mm\:ss,SSS}] - %n%m%n"/>
        </layout>
        <param name="file" value="${Log_Location_Prefix}$/server.log"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5MB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
    </appender>